# Define method in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

This is a bit crazy...

I have a html code the calls a function with `on-click` and it works!

Whan I want to add another function or rename the same function (obviosly also in the `on-click` call), it gives me this error :

```
[dom-bind::_createEventHandler]: listener method `name of function` not defined
```

All whated to do is to **rename** the function.
Whare do you 'define' a function'?

I'm using polymer 1.0

Here's the code that gives me the error.

index.html:

```
<html lang=""> 

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Polymer Starter Kit" />
  <title>ZekTecBell</title>
  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the `app/` directory -->

  <!-- Chrome for Android theme color -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#2E3AA1">

  <!-- Web Application Manifest -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <!-- Tile color for Win8 -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="application-name" content="PSK">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144) -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild-->

  <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- will be replaced with elements/elements.vulcanized.html -->
  <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
  <!-- endreplace-->

  <!-- For shared styles, shared-styles.html import in elements.html -->
  <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>

</head>

<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical" scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
  <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">

    <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
      <!-- Drawer Scroll Header Panel -->
      <paper-scroll-header-panel drawer fixed>

        <!-- Drawer Toolbar -->
        <paper-toolbar id="drawerToolbar">
          <span class="paper-font-title">Menu</span>
        </paper-toolbar>
      </paper-scroll-header-panel>

      <!-- Main Area -->   
      <paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" condenses keep-condensed-header>

        <!-- Main Toolbar --> 
        <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="tall">
          <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
          <span class="flex"></span>

          <!-- Toolbar icons -->
                    <paper-button on-click="testButton">Signup</paper-button>
          <!-- Application name -->
          <div class="middle middle-container center horizontal layout">
            <div class="app-name">Test</div>
          </div>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <!-- Main Content -->
      </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    </paper-drawer-panel>

    <platinum-sw-register auto-register
                          clients-claim
                          skip-waiting
                          on-service-worker-installed="displayInstalledToast">
      <platinum-sw-cache default-cache-strategy="fastest"
                         cache-config-file="cache-config.json">
      </platinum-sw-cache>
    </platinum-sw-register>
    --> 

  </template>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js:

```
  app.displayInstalledToast = function() {
    // Check to make sure caching is actually enabled—it won't be in the dev environment.
    if (!Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('platinum-sw-cache').disabled) {
      Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('#caching-complete').show();
    }
  };

  // Listen for template bound event to know when bindings
  // have resolved and content has been stamped to the page
  app.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
    console.log('Our app is ready to rock!');
  });

  // See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1381
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
  });

  // Main area's paper-scroll-header-panel custom condensing transformation of
  // the appName in the middle-container and the bottom title in the bottom-container.
  // The appName is moved to top and shrunk on condensing. The bottom sub title
  // is shrunk to nothing on condensing.
  window.addEventListener('paper-header-transform', function(e) {
    var appName = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('#mainToolbar .app-name');
    var middleContainer = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('#mainToolbar .middle-container');
    var bottomContainer = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('#mainToolbar .bottom-container');
    var detail = e.detail;
    var heightDiff = detail.height - detail.condensedHeight;
    var yRatio = Math.min(1, detail.y / heightDiff);
    // appName max size when condensed. The smaller the number the smaller the condensed size.
    var maxMiddleScale = 0.50;
    var auxHeight = heightDiff - detail.y;
    var auxScale = heightDiff / (1 - maxMiddleScale);
    var scaleMiddle = Math.max(maxMiddleScale, auxHeight / auxScale + maxMiddleScale);
    var scaleBottom = 1 - yRatio;

    // Move/translate middleContainer
    Polymer.Base.transform('translate3d(0,' + yRatio * 100 + '%,0)', middleContainer);

    // Scale bottomContainer and bottom sub title to nothing and back
    Polymer.Base.transform('scale(' + scaleBottom + ') translateZ(0)', bottomContainer);

    // Scale middleContainer appName
    Polymer.Base.transform('scale(' + scaleMiddle + ') translateZ(0)', appName);
  });

  // Scroll page to top and expand header
  app.scrollPageToTop = function() {
    app.$.headerPanelMain.scrollToTop(true);
  };

  app.closeDrawer = function() {
    app.$.paperDrawerPanel.closeDrawer();
  };

  app.testButton = function() {
    console.log('login?');
  }


})(document);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would be easier if you would show some code.

Comment: `app.testButton` is your function definition. How are you trying to rename it?

Comment: no. using app.testButton dosn't work. In the begining it was a diffarent name and it worked fine, now it dosn't. Could it be because I'm using polymer 1.0 and not 1.4?

Comment: It's better to use **on-tap** because it works on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<paper-button onclick="testButton">Signup</paper-button>
```

and better use ontab instead of onclick.

**Edit**

I was wrong. Actually on-click is the right listener to use.

I actually think it is either a problem of your html Markup or your Polymer version. I tried this code and it worked for me:

```
<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical" scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
  <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">

    <paper-button on-click="testButton">Signup</paper-button>

  </template>

  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also you are missing a simicolon here:

```
  app.testButton = function() {
    console.log('login?');
  }; // here
```

Maybe you need to start a fresh project if it didn't work for you.

Comment: Then i get this error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: signup is not defined'

Comment: For a few good hours I worked on moving verything to a new file, with testing all the time, and it works. I still don't know what the problem was, but thanks for your help!